# Django file-browser and error 404

Tags: python, django

I'm using django admin site (v1.9.6) and recently installed file-browser for managing images and documents. I followed installation steps and file-browser is shown in admin interface but I cant upload images and documents. When trying to access them 404 errors shows up (also thumbnails are not shown in file-browser page):

```
Page not found (404)
     Request Method:    GET
     Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/uploads/aaaaaaaaaaalula.png
```

But the file is there, if I make

```
ls media/uploads/aaaaaaaaaaalula.png
```

it shows the file, so it's uploaded.

my settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/admin/'
```

and url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from filebrowser.sites import site


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/filebrowser', include(site.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Thanks in advance for help.

C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

The issue was that I was testing django-filebrowser with development server

Answer (score 0):

You are not putting url for displaying image.
In setting.py-

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/") 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' 
In URLs.py--
Url(r'^media/(?^<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',{'document_root':
 settings.MEDIA_ROOT,}),
```

I think it can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    #your urls
]

if settings.DEBUG: # will be 'True' in development
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```